# ¿Por qué este hilo no sale de wait() si otro hilo le está notificando?

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo esta clase Pizzeria en la que tengo dos metodos synchronized que van a ejecutar dos hilos diferentes. Después de un tiempo en sleep mandan un notifyAll para que el otro hilo que se encuentre en wait empiece a funcionar. Las clases que ejecutaran esos métodos serán Cocinero y Repartidor.

El problema es que al hacer notifyAll, el hilo que está esperando sigue esperando hasta que el otro entra en wait cuando lo que busco es que los hilos se ejecuten de forma separada.

Clase Pizzeria

```
public class Pizzeria {
    private int bandeja;
    private int pedidos;
    public Pizzeria() {
        bandeja=0;
        pedidos=50;
    }
    
    public synchronized void preparar() {
        
        if (pedidos>0 && bandeja<5) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random()*500));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Pedido preparado y listo para entregar");
            pedidos--;
            bandeja++;
            notifyAll();
        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println("Cocinero espera");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public synchronized void repartir() {
        if (bandeja>0) {
            bandeja--;
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random()*10));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Pedido entregado");
            notifyAll();
        }
        else {
            try {
                System.out.println("Repartidor espera");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Pizzeria p = new Pizzeria();
        Cocinero c = new Cocinero(p);
        Repartidor r1 = new Repartidor(p);
        Repartidor r2 = new Repartidor(p);
        Repartidor r3 = new Repartidor(p);
        
        r1.start();
        r2.start();
        r3.start();
        c.start();
        
    }
}
```

Clase Cocinero

```
public class Cocinero extends Thread{
    private Pizzeria pizzeria;
    public Cocinero(Pizzeria p){
        pizzeria=p;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            pizzeria.preparar();
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Clase repartidor

```
public class Repartidor extends Thread{
    private Pizzeria pizzeria;
    public Repartidor(Pizzeria p) {
        pizzeria=p;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            pizzeria.repartir();
        }
        
    }
}
```